# Should I alert a conventional 'Pass'

Tags: bridge, bidding

My partner and I have a pretty neat system for bidding against opponents opening a weak 2 (2 in a Major = <11 HCP, 6-card; 2 Diamonds as either the Multi or weak with diamonds). In this system, if North opens and East passes, that pass has a specific meaning.

Does this 'Pass' need to be alerted? Is it reglementary to alert a 'Pass'?

Same goes for Double, we have some specific agreements for Double in this defense as well. Does that need to be alerted?

Comment: If your Double in this situation is primarily take-out, not a two-way bid, and shows a strength of at least 10 HCP but does not promise a significantly stronger hand such as 17+ HCP, then it is *probably* not alertable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the English Bridge Union Blue Book (Rules and Ethics):

> Unless it is announceable (
>   see 4
>   D
>   , 4
>   E, 4
>   F
>   and 4
>   G
>   ), a pass
>   or bid must be alerted if
>   it
>   :
>   (a)
>   is not natural; or
>   (b)
>   is natural but has a potentially unexpected meaning

('Natural' has a long paragraph of definition; a natural pass is
"A pass
which does not unexpectedly convey values or specify suit holdings.")

So yes, if your bid (including pass or double) is conventional it must be alerted.

Comment: Rules can be different in different places.  For conventional passes, it's the same in the ACBL (i.e. North America).

Comment: Also, any pass that promises a minimum strength > 0 HCP is alertable, without any exceptions that I can think of right now. Unless it is part of a constructive defense it is also probably a restricted bid that could only be played in extended team play or other unrestricted events.